# Hide the first image inside post before any text (no paragraph available)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In Blogger paragraphs aren't wrapped in `<p></p>` tags and they are displayed as plain text with line breaks (`<br/>`). I want to hide the first image that appears before any text and not the first image if there is any text before it.

For example:

```
This is some text (image AFTER text should be visible):

    <img src="image.png"/>
```

Hide image in this example:

```
    <img src="image.png"/>

This is some text (image BEFORE text should be hidden)
```

Comment: You can define a condition checking for the `nextSibling` if it is a text node then hide the image. Something like that:
 `if(img.nextSibling.nodeName === "#text")  {  /// hide this image  }`

Comment: @konrud's solution won't work for obvious reasons.  show us the rest of the html

Comment: Hi DCR, the html is simply something like that <div class="post-body"><img src="image.png"/><br /><br />Text<br /><br />Another paragraph<br /><br />etc. etc</div>. Sometimes the first image is before any text and this doesn't look good when I set the first image as featured with a specific styling because the first image that is already featured appears immediately after the featured section. Hope this makes sense. Sometimes the first image appears after some text and that's perfectly fine since it isn't too close to the featured section.

Answer (score 0):

since there is no way to manipulate text nodes in CSS, here is a clean way to fix your issue:

with absolute positioning the image to make it appear before text with adding padding the the parent post div

```css
.post {
  padding-top: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.post img {
  display: none;
}

.post img:first-of-type {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  Hello there is a hidden image below Hello there is a hidden image below
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</div>

<div class="post">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /> Hello there is a hidden image below Hello there is a hidden image below
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</div>
```